# Unix substr in shell script?

Tags: shell, scripting, substr

I have a string like sample.txt.pgp and I want to return sample.txt in a shell script (but, the string length will vary, so, basically all of the characters before the ".pgp").  Is there a substr function?  Like, if I did `substr('sample.txt.pgp', -4, 0)`, is it supposed to return sample.txt?  Right now it isn't, so I'm wondering if I have the syntax wrong, or maybe substr isn't a function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `basename`:

```
$ basename sample.txt.pgp .pgp
sample.txt
```

Use backticks or `$()` to put the result in a variable if you want:

```
$ FILE=sample.txt.pgp
$ VARIABLE=$(basename "$FILE" .pgp)
$ echo $VARIABLE
sample.txt
```

Comment: Interesting that you use the '-s suffix' notation; that is not standardized by POSIX; the classic notation would be `$(basename $file .pgp)` (assuming the name is held in a variable '$file').

Comment: @Jonathan Yes indeed!  I just did a `man basename` on my OS X machine here, and saw the `-s` option; it was a bit more flexible (can handle more than one string), I didn't know it wasn't POSIX.  I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Edited; I also put some double quotes in to support spaces in the filename.

Answer (score 3):

```
a='sample.txt.pgp'
echo ${a%.*}   # sample.txt (minimal match)
echo ${a%%.*}  # sample     (maximal match)
```

Comment: This looks interesting...  What's the dollar sign and % represent?  Do you have a page that kinda explains this or anything?

Comment: @KnockKnockWhosThere: Read http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02 for more info. :-)

Comment: And a more constrained version: `${a%.pgp}` only removes a `.pgp` extension if it is present; the original will remove any extension at all (which might be useful in some cases).

Answer (score 0):

`filename sample.txt.pgp`  returns sample.txt, I believe. 
(use backticks)

Comment: @Jefromi: I think they're referring to `basename`.

Comment: `basename` is for stripping leading directory components. It can also remove suffixes, but only when you know what they are. `basename sample.txt.pgp .pgp` will print "sample.txt".